# Apache mod_wsgi slowloris DoS protection

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi, denial-of-service

Assuming the following setup:

- Apache server 2.4
- mpm_prefork with default settings (256 workers?)
- Default Timeout (300s)
- High KeepAliveTimeout (100s)
- reqtimeout_mod enabled with the following config: `RequestReadTimeout header=62,MinRate=500 body=62,MinRate=500`
- Outdated mod_wsgi 3.5 using Daemon mode with 15 threads and 1 process
- AWS ElasticBeanstalk's load balancer acting as a reverse proxy to apache with 60s idle connection timeout
- Python/Django being the wsgi application

A simple slowloris attack like the one described here, using a "slow" request body: https://www.blackmoreops.com/2015/06/07/attack-website-using-slowhttptest-in-kali-linux/

The above attack, with just 15 requests (same as mod_wsgi threads) can easily lock the server until a timeout happens, either due to:

- Load balancer timeout (60s) happens due to no data sent, this kills the apache connection and mod_wsgi can once again serve requests
- Apache RequestReadTimeout happens due to data being sent, but not enough, again mod_wsgi is able to serve requests after this

However, with just 15 concurrent "slow" requests, I was able to lock the server up to 60 seconds.

Repeating the same but with a more bizarre number, like 4096 requests, pretty much locks the server permanently since there will be always a new request that needs to be served by mod_wsgi once the previous times out.

I would expect that the load balancer should handle/detect this before even sending requests to apache, which it already does for similar attacks (partial headers, or tcp syn flood attacks never hit apache which is nice)

What options are available to help against this? I know there's no failproof option since these kind of attacks are difficult to detect and protect, but it's quite silly that the server can be locked that easily.

Also, if the wsgi application never reads request body, I would expect for the issue to not happen as well since the request should return immediately, but I'm not sure about this or the internals of mod_wsgi, for example, this is true when using a local dev wsgi server (the attack files since the request body is never read) but the attack succeeds when using mod_wsgi, which leads me to think it tries to read the body even before sending it to the wsgi code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slowloris is a very simple Denial-of-Service attack. This is easy to detect and block.

Detecting and preventing DoS and DDos attacks are complex topics with many solutions. In your case you are making the situation worse by using outdated software and picking a low worker thread count so that the problem arises quickly.

A combination of services are available that would be used to manage Dos and DDos attacks.

The front-end of the total system would be protected by a firewall. Typically this firewall would include a Web Application Firewall to understand the nuances of HTTP protocols. In the AWS world, Amazon WAF and Shield are commonly used.

Another service that helps is a CDN. Amazon CloudFront uses Amazon Shield so it has good DDoS support.

The next step is to combine load balancers with auto scaling mechanisms. When the health checks start to fail (caused by Slowloris), the auto scaler will begin launching new instances and terminating failed instances. However, a sustained Slowloris attack will just hit the new servers. This is why the Web Application Firewall needs to detect the attack and start blocking it.

For your studies, take a look at **mod_reqtimeout**. This is an effective and tuneable solution for Apache for most Slowloris attacks.

[Update]

In the Amazon DDoS White Paper June 2015, Slowloris is specifically mentioned.

> On AWS, you can use Amazon CloudFront and AWS WAF to defend your
>   application against these attacks. Amazon CloudFront allows you to
>   cache static content and serve it from AWS Edge Locations that can
>   help reduce the load on your origin. **Additionally, Amazon CloudFront
>   can automatically close connections from slow-reading or slow-writing
>   attackers (e.g., Slowloris)**.

[Amazon DDoS White Paper June 2015](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/DDoS_White_Paper_June2015.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation, I definitely haven't checked amazon WAF and shield, I guess that would be the best solution. About  mod_reqtimeout, that's set by default when using aws elasticbeanstalk with a high value (>60s) so it behaves nicely with the load balanacer connection draining, but with the downside of allowing easier slowloris attacks

Comment: I just remembered the AWS DDos White Paper which has really good information and I recommend you taking a look at it if you have not. Take a look at CloudFront specifically for Slowloris. I just updated my answer with more information.

Comment: Sadly cloudfront is only for static files, I will research on AWS WAF

Comment: That is not true at all. CloudFront works just fine for dynamic content. Here is a link: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/dynamic-content/

Comment: Others apache modules can be used to mitigate and block slowloris attacks like mod_qos and mod_evasive.

Answer (score 1):

In mod_wsgi daemon mode there are a bunch of options to further help to combat such attacks by recovering from it and discarding queued requests as well which have been waiting too long. Try your tests using `mod_wsgi-express` as it defines defaults for a lot of these options whereas when using mod_wsgi yourself directly, there are no defaults. Use `mod_wsgi-express start-server --help` to see what defaults are. The actual options you want to look at for mod_wsgi daemon mode are `request-timeout`, `connect-timeout`, `socket-timeout` and `queue-timeout`. There are also other options related to buffer sizes and listener backlog you can play with. Do note that ultimately the listen backlog of the main Apache worker processes can still be an issue because it usually defaults to 500, which means a lot of requests can queue up stuck before you can even tag them with a time so as to help discard the backlog by tracking queue time.

You can find the documentation at:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html

On the point of whether mod_wsgi reads the request body before sending it, no it doesn't. Apache itself because it reads in block may partially read the request body when reading the headers, but it shouldn't block on it. Once the full request headers are passed off to mod_wsgi and sent through to the daemon process, then mod_wsgi will start transferring the request body.

Comment: Hi Graham, good thing you are around! I'm trying to understand why mod_wsgi threads block and stop handling new requests when there's a slow request body, but the wsgi script returns a response instantly (without reading the body). Shouldn't it kill w/e request was happening if the script returns a response? I can provide sample logs of this if you need it.

Comment: It occurs because Apache is still obligated to read the request body even if your application doesn't. This is to support subsequent requests in a keep alive connection. Because proxying is involved, the proxying part will get stuck because it will only start reading the response until it has been able to send the request body. The proxying doesn't really support both way HTTP traffic. To change this behaviour to stop reading request if complete request is returned before request body is read and is not keep alive is complicated and although on TODO list for a long time never got around to it.

Comment: Should add that this issue with proxying is not unique to mod_wsgi and also occurs with CGI and SCGI as well. Not sure about FASTCGI.

Comment: I see, thanks for the detailed explanation, so pretty much the only way around it would be disabling keep alive, that way the connection is closed once the response is returned?

Comment: No. That will not help in this specific case as the proxying code is still going to read content before response. You need to rely on timeout and rate detection in mod_reqtimeout and other timeout mechanisms in mod_wsgi daemon mode. Only other thing can do is set ``LimitRequestBody`` to 1 for URLs where they don't accept any request content. That will at least additionally combat trickling of request content to avoid rate detection in mod_reqtimeout. Does mean that anyone attacking site just needs to work out what URLs actually genuinely handle POST requests.

Comment: You should also though set sensible values for ``LimitRequestBody`` in URLs which do handle content. Have unlimited value and you could do a memory attack instead by continually trickling data through at fast enough rate.

Comment: From what you said, the response can not be returned/sent until the whole request is read due to how the proxying works, however, on the server (apache) logs it shows that the response was sent back instantly and the request timed out 1 minute after, doesn't that mean the response was actually sent before reading the whole request? Is it just some odd behavior of the server logs times and not actually what really happened?

Comment: And FWIW, using async WSGI servers don't necessarily solve the problems. You can use a memory attack on Waitress and also Tornado servers. So you can protect against script kiddies, but if someone is determined to take a site down, they can usually find a way by relying on how the application is implemented. This is why purpose built front end solutions in front of the web server is generally better, rather than relying of your web server to handle it all.

Comment: Are you sure you are using mod_wsgi daemon mode? What you are describing should only be the case in embedded mode. Can you provide the test WSGI application you are using? And what messages do you get in the Apache error log.

Comment: It may also be better to take this discussion to the mod_wsgi mailing list.

Comment: I agree Graham, I will open an issue on the mailing list. But yes I'm definitely using daemon mode.

Comment: Opened an issue to discuss this here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/wSpNBD-yKwo if you are interested.

Comment: Seen it. Coming off a busy weekend but will try and look at it today.

Answer (score 0):

**Soloution:**
If you are getting hit, I recommend you go to a provider that protects against DDoS attacks. However your best bet would be to programatically block the IP once it has been decided that it is being malicious. If you receive two large `Content-Length` `POST` requests than you should block the IP for a few minutes for suspicious activities. Many large companies are very cheap, and some of them are free for the basic package such as [Cloud Flare](https://CloudFlare.com). I use them for my company and I am beyond happy to have them!

Edit: Their job is literally just to protect you. That is it.

Comment: Hi Sean, I'm not getting hit, this is a research question mostly. Getting a provider to protect against it is the obvious option that I'm trying to avoid. But you are pretty much saying that any protection should really come from the outside and trying to set up apache or the load balancer properly is pretty much useless? I would expect at least some tuning to defend against silly attacks like the one I tried, and getting a provider only against "real" attacks.

Comment: @user1777914 The best bet is a provider, but considering you dont want one you will have to create your own kind of provider. Your firewall rules will have to be tight, and you will need to configure your web server to have a strict set of rules preventing slow loris and floods in general. Though it is usually just a matter of IP blocking, you would still need to configure your own rules.